# Generate a 200kHz varying voltage signal

Tags: frequency, timer, modulation

I have a 12V DC supply from just a normal household converter.
We have to  make a circuit which will output an 200kHz AC signal with a p2p voltage of 3-12 volts depending on a strain gauge. 3 being no load and 12 being complete failure.

We have been given 2 555 timer ICs but I really don't see where to start with this; anyone able to give me a push in the right direction with any part of this?

Comment: This is an amplitude modulation problem, Gricey.  You need to condition your strain gage signal to provide the correct signal, and then multiply (i.e., modulate) it by the 200KHz wave.  That's a push in the right direction, and if you can convince me this isn't coursework that you're supposed to be doing on your own, we'll see if we can dig up something more specific.

Comment: Use the strain gauge in the RC timing circuit on a triangle wave generator.

Comment: @ScottSeidman it's University coursework; not trying to hide that by any means. Some 'modern teaching' thing where we are meant to learn from eachother and the internet; no lectures or textbook. Stupidest thing ever, anyway, my ranting is irrelevant.

Comment: @ScottSeidman thanks for the push onto a new topic of research, I'll go read some more theory then see if I can't get closer

Comment: The easiest thing you could do would be to vary the frequency, but that doesn't seem to satisfy the requirement.  A likely plausible sort of signal you could try to generate would be a 200 KHz triangle wave which builds to a peak amplitude varying based on the strain gauge reading.  You could do this either as something which charges a capacitor at a varying rate for the full duration of the each 1/200Khz period, or something which charges it with a fixed circuit for a variable fraction of each period.

Comment: You will want to look at a collection of various 555 circuits, and take some time to understand what the functional blocks within the IC do within those circuits, as well as how you might re-purpose them.  Keep in mind that most 555 circuits charge between fixed threshold voltages, so you may need some trickery or have the 555 control the charging of another capacitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of parts to this problem.  The first is the strain gage.  Generally, these are implemented via a *Wheatstone Bridge* circuit.  Step 2 is conditioning the output of the Wheatstone Bridge, which can be pretty easily handled with an *Instrumentation Amplifier*.  The final step would be the *Amplitude Modulation* with the 200KHz sine wave.

It's not clear to me what power supplies you've been given, which can have impact on your design.  If you only have a positive DC supply you have to create a negative supply, or use integrated circuits that can handle single supply functionality and condition your signals a little bit differently.

It's also not clear whether you're given the 200kHz wave or need to create one.  That might be what your 555 timer is intended to do, but its not necessarily how I would choose to create a sine wave.  You might search on *oscillator circuits*.

Those are the level of pointers I'd give to a student.  If you offer more info about the class, maybe its appropriate to offer more targeted help.  As it is, the above search terms should be of some pretty major help.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers; the brief has been updated to say we can make any form of wave including square wave which makes it a lot easier. Most of the problem I was having was trying to generate a 200kHz clean sine wave from scratch.
Thanks again